# Storing local docker images on External HDD boot2docker

Tags: docker

I'm using docker on my macbook air which unfortunately has quite limited hard drive space (120gb).

Was wondering how I could store containers on my external drive instead of the default (which I believe is /var/lib/docker/) ?

EDIT: It is in fact not /var/lib/docker - when using boot2docker I believe the files are stored on the virtualbox instance.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by changing file location in docker.
You can go to Preferences->Advanced, and under the storage path change the location to your external hard drive.

[View the screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ekuU.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

After clearing your macbook folder, mount your external hard drive on that path:

```
mount -t <fstype> -o defaults /dev/<your device> /var/lib/docker/
```

For use with **boot2docker**, try with something like:

```
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=50 /dev/<your device> /var/lib/docker/
```

where `<your device>` could be for example `sdb`.